# university project (bash shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so i have a script to compose
it needs to be a script managing a .dat file with 10000+ lines
the formation of the .dat is like so :

## id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed

933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox

1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer

4194|Do|Há»“ ChÃ­|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer

**The script will work under specific commands entered in terminal**. For example :

At first i need to show the whole .dat file using this command
./tool.sh -f   (First command)   (tool.sh is the script and file is the .dat file)

also it needs to get a specific #id via the command and show the firstname the lastname and bday of that #id
command : ./tool.sh -f < file > -id < id > (Second command)

there are also some other assigments that this script needs to accomplish using certain commands like(./tool.sh --firstnames -f < file >)and ( ./tool.sh -f < file > --edit < id > < column > < value >)

i have managed to figure out the code for the first command (./tool.sh -f < file >  ) 
But how can the second command be accomplished? how could the columns be separated?

p.s. the script needs to work on every .dat file with the same structure

here is the code that is needed for the first terminal command
while getopts ":f" opt; do
   case $opt in
      f)
        while read line; do echo "$line"; done < persons.dat
        ;;
        \?)
       echo "Wrong opt: -$OPTARG" >&2
       ;;
   esac
done

Comment: Please show your code to date. And please ask a more specific question. What is the "second command" required to do and what *specific* difficulty do you have in implementing it (don't know how to parse the command line? don't know how to find the id?, etc). We can't help you unless you tell us exactly what you don't know how to do.

Comment: while getopts ":f" opt; do
  case $opt in
    f)
      while read line; do echo "$line"; done < persons.dat
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Wrong opt: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
thats the code/answer for the ./tool.sh -f < file > terminal command
by second command i mean the ./tool.sh -f < file > -id < id >
and by accomplished i mean that i dont know the code for it. This command needs to scan the .dat file for a specific #id and show the name and birthdate of the person with that id

Comment: Please add it to the question not in comments where it its unreadable. Click edit under the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand the pronunciation of this exercise...Beyond copying-pasting it.. did you do anything else? like researching?